# How to send and receive messages between client and server in python?

Tags: python, sockets

I am learning socket programming in python.I am sorry because English is my second language.
I want to make a program that first client send a message to server and then server replies client.
This is my code:

server.py:

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 1234))

s.listen(5)

full_msg = ""
while True:
    con, add = s.accept()
    print(f"connection is established via {add}")
    while True:
        data = con.recv(16)
        if not data:
            break
        full_msg += data.decode()
    print(full_msg)
    full_msg = ""
    con.send("Thank you".encode())
    con.close()
```

client.py:

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 1234))

s.send("Hello".encode())

full_msg = ""
while True:
    data = s.recv(16)
    if not data:
        break
    full_msg += data.decode()
print(full_msg)
```

I expect in the server script output of "Hello" and in the client script "Thank you" but it doesn't have any out put.Both of them when receiving data doesn't will be stopped.Why???

**Update:**
I used shutdown method.It got better. I change my code in order to make a connection between client and server .In an infinite loop we ask client for message then send that to server until client enters "q". Now client can send a message and receive a message from server but the second time when client wants to send a message client will getting an error "BrokenPipeError: [WinError 10058] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket had already been shut down in that direction with a previous shutdown call".
How can I fix that??

server.py:

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 1234))

s.listen(5)

full_msg = ""
while True:
    con, add = s.accept()
    print(f"connection is established via {add}")
    while True:
        data = con.recv(16)
        if not data:
            break
        full_msg += data.decode()
    print(full_msg)
    full_msg = ""
    con.send("Thank you".encode())
    con.shutdown(1)
```

client.py:

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 1234))

while True:
    msg = input("What do you want to send -> ")
    if msg == "q":
        break
    s.send(msg.encode())
    s.shutdown(1)

    full_msg = ""
    while True:
        data = s.recv(16)
        if not data:
            break
        full_msg += data.decode()
    print(full_msg)
```

Comment: The server is waiting on `con.recv(16);` for the next chunk of data but it never comes. Meanwhile the client sends "Hello" and then waits for something from the server, but the server is waiting for something from the client. Specifically, the server is waiting for an EOF indication. The client can do that by closing its socket, but then it won't be able to receive anything. The solution is for the client to call `s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR);` to close down just the write half of the client socket. This is also the read half of the server socket and thus will cause an EOF.

Comment: @JamesKPolk: You should turn this comment into an answer!

Comment: @Blckknght: I'm trying to avoid answering questions in the sockets tag, one of the more insecure users downvotes them without comment. It's disheartening to contribute effort and have it pissed on. Feel free to make it part of your answer though.

Comment: If somebody's voting inappropriately, you should flag a relevant post for moderator attention, rather than giving in to their terrorism. I don't really know enough about socket programming to answer myself, I had a vague idea that `recv` was going to block and that was the problem with the code, but I don't know anything about the `shutdown` method.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I updated my post.Can you please help me??